# download pdf and open it in print dialogue directly

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I'm developing a web app which dynamically generate .pdf slips. when user clicks on download or print button, pdf file generate and getting download.Now, i just want to do that downloaded file should open in Print dialogue.
Please guide me and help.
thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You cannot start the printing of a file from the browser. What you can do is create an HTML page instead of a PDF, then call `window.print()`

Comment: Dear,Can i open downloaded .pdf in a new tab ?